# Update to Constraint-Layout 2 destroys working layouts

Tags: android, user-interface, android-constraintlayout, xml-layout

After updating `com.google.android.material:material` and `androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout` from 1.1.0 and 1.1.3 to 1.3.0 and 2.0.4 my layout gets squished. I've got a custom view constraint-layout inside a ScrollView->LinearLayout. The problem is that after updating said dependencies the view gets squished and doesn't use wrap_content anymore to claim the height it needs. (The preview matches the running version, cache clear/rebuild doesn't help.)

I probably messed up something but can't figure out what exactly.

[image: Squished ConstraintLayout view inside linear layout]

[image: ConstraintLayout as per definition]

Fragment Layout:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <my.app.ui.editor.AssetAttributeView
            android:id="@+id/assetName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:label="@string/hint_asset_name" />
       <!-- and some more of them.. -->
    </linearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

CustomView Layout:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/editor_view_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/asset_attribute_view_label"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:labelFor="@id/asset_attribute_view_text"
        android:saveEnabled="false"
        android:text="@string/PLACEHOLDER"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/asset_attribute_view_switch"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/asset_attribute_view_switch"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/asset_attribute_view_text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="start|top"
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:saveEnabled="false"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/asset_attribute_view_label"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/asset_attribute_view_switch" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat
        android:id="@+id/asset_attribute_view_switch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:saveEnabled="false"
        android:text="@string/editor_switch_update"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/asset_attribute_view_label"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: have same issue, `layout_constrainedHeight="true"` does not helps

Comment: The same issue, @proc Do we have any updates regarding the fix?